# Move Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

### Help, how to pass this code (Activity) to code (Fragment), how it should be?

```
public class SelectProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ProfileAdapter.ProfileAdapterItemCallBack {

    private List<Profile> Profiles;
    private RecyclerView morral;
    private GridLayoutManager correa;
    private ProfileAdapter adapter;
    private SharedPreferencesController spc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }
    public void crearPerfil(View view){
        Intent inten=new Intent(this,RegistrarPerfil.class);
        startActivity(inten);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        spc = new SharedPreferencesController(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_profile);
        //la lista donde se agregaran los perfiles
        Profiles = new ArrayList<Profile>();
        //Consulta para obtener todos los perfiles
        Profiles=App.getProfFromUser(spc.getPrefUID());
        adapter = new ProfileAdapter(Profiles, this);
        if (Profiles.isEmpty()){
            App.showMessage("No se encontraron Perfiles",this);
        }
        else
        {
            //RecyclerView donde se van a mostrar los elementos
            morral = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv_all_profiles);
            correa = new GridLayoutManager(this,3);
            morral.setLayoutManager(correa);
            morral.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onProfileItemSelected(Profile perfil) {
        spc.saveProfile(perfil);
        Intent inte = new Intent(this, CategoryActivity.class);
        startActivity(inte);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, read about Fragments I'll suggest. You will definitely figure out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many things going wrong in your code.

- Don't do such things in your onResume(). setContentView(..) should be done in Activity onCreate(..) callback. In some special scenarios, setContentView(..) can be done based on different conditions.
- May be its good to start with Android resources, there are many samples by Google. [Google samples for Android](https://github.com/googlesamples)
- Please read android docs [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html)